# Mathematica 10.X benchmark report for high-end surface pro 4/surface book?

Tags: performance-tuning, system-performance, hardware, testing-and-verification

Recently, I am seriously considering purchasing the high-end surface device (with intel i7 and maximal RAM). Mathematica will be one of the main applications. Since it is not a full or traditional laptop in some sense, I was just wondering if anyone could kindly provide the result of the built-in benchmark feature, which is simply given by the following commands. Showing the 'System Comparison' graph and 'Detailed Timings' graph will suffice.

```
Needs["Benchmarking`"];
BenchmarkReport[]
```

A minor issue is I am not sure whether there is anything like underclocking or bottlenecking when the device is on battery rather than plugged. So if only anyone can check the difference.
Result of either high-end surface pro 4 or high-end surface book will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes the benchmark for a high-end surface book with i7-6600U (2.6 up to 3.4 GHz, 4 MB cache, 15 W), which might be not quite different from surface pro 4 with intel i7-6650U (2.2 up to 3.4 GHz, 4 MB cache, 15 W).

**Plugged**
[image: plugged1]
[image: plugged2]
**On battery**
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171026/11125